# What do I do if my fighting fish is just lying at the bottom of the tank, barely moving but eating a little?

Tags: fish

He has these little fins on the side of his face that keep going out and in. He's just lying in the corner of the tank. We fed him earlier and he didn't eat as much. I took out about a third of dirty water and added new water in. We also added a heater. This is hiM. [image]

Comment: Can you give us some more details, have you changed the water lately, any changes, how long you've had him, etc Thanks

Comment: What filtration do you use? What level is ammonia, nitrit and nitrate?